# Number of points in .las by PDAL from Python

Tags: python, point, pdal

I need to recieve the number of points that .las file has from Python and save it as variable. For now I'm doing it like this:

```
def execute(self, pipeline):
    pipeline = pdal.Pipeline(json.dumps(pipeline))
    pipeline.validate()
    self.points_num += int(pipeline.execute())

def points(self, file):
    pipeline = [
        file,
        {
            "type": "filters.info",
        }
    ]
    self.execute(pipeline)
```

However when file is big (above 2Gb) the procedure takes up to 4 minutes. Is there a smarter way to get number of points?

Comment: Have you tried using the [`laspy`](https://laspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package? Then you can read your LAS file, and then get the number of points with `len(your_las_file.read().points)`

Comment: Yeah, thanks, but I wnat to limit the number of libraries to be used

Comment: [Here](https://pdal.io/apps/info.html#example-2) it is shown that you may use the `-info`, and after that you can `len(dict.items())`.

Comment: Did you get a solution to your problem?